# 401 Unauthorized when creating request using Jquery

Tags: asp.net

I am facing an error when requesting to WEBPageMethod using jquery and get 401 Unauthorized  response and here is code for that

```
function SaveFile(type) {
        var prmList = '';
        prmList += '{"Title":"' + $("#txtTitleAudio").val() + '",';
        prmList += '"Tag":"' + $("#txtAudioTag").val() + '",';
        prmList += '"IsEnable":"' + $('input[name=chkrepost]').is(':checked') + '"}';            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AudioDairy.aspx/SaveAudio",
            data: prmList,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

            },
            error: AjaxFailed
        });
    }
```

and Server Side Code Is

```
 [WebMethod]
public string SaveAudios(string Title, string Tag, string IsEnable)
{
    //lblSelectedDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        return "try Later.";
   // }        
}
```

So Please do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a security/authentication issue with your ASP.NET App. Check out these tips from the [ASP.NET Forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/1190460/2043023.aspx)

> There are several things you need to verify.
>
> 1. Does the web service you are trying to access allow Anonymous
>    Access? Authentication can be tricky
>    for web-to-web calls
> 2. What is the web application running under, IWAM_xxx or IUSR_xxx?
>    Or are you using an
>    application pool running under a specific identity?
> 3. You may want to make sure your web application server's ASPNET or NETWORK
>    SERVICE
>    accounts can access your web service server.

Hope that helps...